# Javascript page visibility api doesn't work with IOS chrome [home button]

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome

I have an application which has video contents. I want video to play only if the page is
visible to user. Page visibility API helped me.

Here is my full code : http://jsfiddle.net/d9bhzL1n/

```
document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function(event) {

  if (!document.hidden) {
    // The page is visible.
  } else {
  // The page is hidden. 
 }
});
```

Please open fiddle and switch tabs.

So far so good. However visibilitychange event doesn't fire on iphone IOS chrome (though works fine with safari). When we click home button I need this event to fire so that I can stop video from playing in background.

Please suggest. Thanks.